# Copy an entire directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm trying to copy a folder and all of its sub folders.

```
copy:{
        test:{
            files:[
                { 
                    src: '/static/**',
                    dest: '/test/'
                }
              ]
        }
}
```

I get the error:

> Unable to create directory "/static" (Error code: EACCES).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change to below and try this.

```
copy:{
        test:{
            files:[
                { 
                    src:['static/**'],
                    dest: 'test/'
                }
              ]
        }
}
```

or

```
files: [
  { src: 'static/**', dest: 'test/' }
]
```

Comment: This outputs: 'Created 2 directories, copied 14 files' but I cant find the test directory - surly it should be relative to where the grunt file is?

Comment: `expand: true, cwd: 'your-starting-directory/',` then the `files`. Should work like a charm.

Comment: @suzumakes: makes sense with expand:true option... if needed

Comment: what does expand true do?

Comment: This will help you... http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically and look at the cwd, src and dest... when expand set to true.